# Error when trying to use cd in a child process in node.js. Resource could not be found

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, electron

Okay, so when I run the following `spawnBot()` function in an Electron window, `cd` throws an error saying that the requested resource could not be found. The following code is part of a file located at `/toggle-gui/scripts.js`, the electron window page is located at `/toggle-gui/pages/index.html` and I want to cd into `/toggle-gui/imported_bots/toggle-base`.

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron');

var selectedBotDir = "./imported_bots/toggle-base";
var bot;

function spawnBot(){
    console.log("Attempting to start Toggle...")
    console.log("Currently selected bot directory: " + selectedBotDir)
    try{
        bot = spawn(`cd ${selectedBotDir}; npm install; npm start`, {shell: true, detached: true});
        console.log("Process ID: " + bot.pid);
        bot.stdout.on('data', data => {
            console.log(data);
        });
        bot.stderr.on('data', data => {
            console.log("ERROR: " + data);
        });
        return bot;
    }
    catch(error){
        console.log(error);
        console.log("Toggle failed to start. There should be extra logging output above.")
    }
}
```

Some help here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The use of `./` in paths makes them relative, which means "treat this path as a subdirectory of the directory you're currently in." However, this "directory you're currently in" does not have to be the directory your Node.js code is located in but rather the directory the shell process you're creating using `spawn ()` was spawned in, which, by default will be set to the directory you're running your Electron app from (i.e. where you ran `npm run` and not where your script is located).

Thus, you have to tell Node.js in what directory the shell process executing your OS code should be run in, which can be done by passing a `cwd` (current working directory) parameter to `span ()` as stated in its [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options). The current script's directory can be accessed in Node.js using `__dirname`, which would lead to the following code:

```js
bot = spawn(`cd ${selectedBotDir}; npm install; npm start`, {shell: true, detached: true, cwd: __dirname});
```

However, using this method you can get rid of the `cd` step entirely as you can directly set the `cwd` to be equal to `selectedBotDir`, given that that path actually starts with the current directory:

```js
var selectedBotDir = `${__dirname}/imported_bots/toggle-base`;
// ...
try {
    bot = spawn(`npm install; npm start`, {shell: true, detached: true, cwd: selectedBotDir});
    // ...
} // ...
```

Please be aware, however, that this could break in multiple ways once you decide to package and distribute your app. By default, Electron apps will be packed into TAR-like archives, ASAR files, which will then be the `__dirname`. However, the OS cannot directly read from ASAR files and will once again fail to "find the requested resource". Also, if you're planning to distribute your app, don't expect users to also have NPM installed.